# Setting address manually on JGroups

Tags: java, jgroups

I'd like to create a simple chat application where the user can send message to a specific user. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7593273/6220384), I can send a message to a specific target using the target's address. The problem is, I can't get a specific user address without tracking his id on the channel's view. Is there anyway to set a user address so I can generate a unique address for each registered user and then use it as their address each time they try to login? With that, I can get their address based their username from data storage.

Comment: I personally don't think that jgroups is the right choice here ..have you checked what is the maximum number of nodes that can be added to cluster ... go with simple java application or use sockets / websockets for this ..

Comment: @user666 I'm just trying to use JGroups here. I create this app for the sake of learning. And for the maximum nodes, I never think of that.

Comment: I will say then JGroups is quite advanced from learning point of view..search for chat server using websockets that should work and easy as well ...

Comment: @user666 I'm trying to learn JGroups. I'm messing around with the codes from [this tutorial](http://www.jgroups.org/tutorial-3.x/html/ch02.html) they provided.